# Load after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Never done this before. I want to load an a href's after 5 seconds once the page has loaded.

I am working on a script but it is not working.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="div1">
    <a id="single" href="#">Single Play</a>
    <a id="multi" href="#">Head to Head</a>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    function ahref(){
        $("#div1").show();
    };
    window.setTimeout( ahref, 5000 ); // 5 seconds
})
```

Where have a gone wrong?

Comment: Is `#div1` in hidden state before ?

Comment: What isn't working about it? Do you have CSS that hides the DIV by default?

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/08y8vvrn/1/

Comment: Change `$(window).load` to `$(document).ready`. [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is for loading in remote data.

Comment: An important question: Did you include JQ library to your page?

Comment: @RayonDabrei haven't even tired to style the div in css thats why i am confused

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thank you i will try that now

Comment: @jerneva There's no point in calling `show()` if it isn't hidden in the first place. Why did you think that would work?

Comment: @Barmar that is so weird does not work at all for me

Comment: @MikeC not true, `$(window).on('load')` is called when all CSS and imagery in the page has loaded - it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Barmar lol long night. thank you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right, `$(window).load` is a shorthand for `$(window).on('load')` but that shorthand [has been deprecated.](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: Correct, but `on('load')` still works (and has nothing to do with remote data) and to suggest the use of document.ready instead is completely changing the intent of the code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not true. OP isn't using `on('load')` unless we assume they're using pre-1.8 jQuery, which I think is a poor assumption.

Comment: I didn't assume they were, in fact they obviously aren't. My issue was simply the fact that you said to use document.ready instead of `$(window).on('load', fn)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, I agree with you there. That's just not what was said. Your original phrasing indicates that the current code is "perfectly valid." You are right that they should use `$(window).on('load', fn)` instead of `$(document).ready(fn)`.

Comment: @Barmar still not working. I am so confused

Comment: @jerneva You have two very good answers below. I don't know how we can guess why they don't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  function ahref() {
    $("#div1").show();
  };
  setTimeout(function(){ ahref(); }, 5000);
})
```

```css
#div1{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <a id="single" href="#">Single Play</a>
  <a id="multi" href="#">Head to Head</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to change `ahref` to `function() { ahref(); }`?

Comment: hey mate, @RinoRaj, very strange this didn't work with jquery 2.0.0, https://jsfiddle.net/2692sq1v/

Comment: What's different here to what the OP already claims to have, other than the redundant wrapping of the `ahref()` call in an anonymous function?

Comment: @ameenulla0007, Script should be wrapped in body/head in Fiddle...`onload` will not trigger twice...

Comment: @Barmar I am used to call the function that way. That is all. We can use both way.

Comment: OK, as long as you don't think that's the problem in his original code that needs to be fixed. Your answer should explain what the problem is and how you solved it, not simply dump a bunch of code.

Comment: @Barmar I agree with that. I will edit my answer and try to include why it did not work

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, just the `show()` function works on hidden elements, if the element is already shown it'll has no effect, so you should hide the `div` by default using css class e.g :

```
#div{
    display:none;
}
```

Or javascript function `hide()` e.g :

```
$("#div1").hide();
```

Then your code will work as expected.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#div1").hide();
  
    function ahref(){
        $("#div1").show();
    };
    window.setTimeout( ahref, 2000 ); // 2 seconds
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    <a id="single" href="#">Single Play</a>
    <a id="multi" href="#">Head to Head</a>
</div>
```