# run a ajax call result on load and after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
     jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        async : true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://san.gotdns.ch:8025/json",

        success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        },
        jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
        failure: function () { },
        complete: function (data) {
        $("#div2").html("Success : ");
                if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {

                    //document.write("Success : ");
                    //document.write(data);
                }
                else {
                    document.writeln("Failed");
                }
            }
            // -----
        }
        );
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>
<div id="div2"><h2>Complete</h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I set it to automatically run when page is loaded. and run it after 5 seconds.
Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872880/load-after-5-seconds) but I want to fetch URL not show/hide div !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what's stopping you from following the other page. You can just wrap anything that you wanna run after 5 seconds inside:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
  // Stuff to run after 5 seconds.
}, 5000 );
```

So your code will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Instead of button click, change this.
        setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery.support.cors = true;
          $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://san.gotdns.ch:8025/json",
            success: function(result) {
              $("#div1").html(result);
            },
            jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
            failure: function() {},
            complete: function(data) {
              $("#div2").html("Success : ");
              if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {

                //document.write("Success : ");
                //document.write(data);
              } else {
                document.writeln("Failed");
              }
            }
          });
        }, 5000);
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="div1">
      <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

    <button>Get External Content</button>
    <div id="div2">
      <h2>Complete</h2>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

You had some extra unnecessary tags. I removed them. Please don't use `document.write` function, as it is dangerous. Instead, use an element and update its contents. The following code:

```
  if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {

    //document.write("Success : ");
    //document.write(data);
  } else {
    document.writeln("Failed");
  }
```

Should be replaced with:

```
  if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {
    $("#div2").append(data);
  } else {
    $("#div2").append("An Error Occurred");
  }
```

Comment: thanks Praveen, what is the difference between result variable on success and data variable on complete ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz `complete` and `success` are almost the same. You need to use only one.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz `success` The function gets passed two arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the 'dataType' parameter, and a string describing the status. `complete` The function gets passed two arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object and a string describing the type of success of the request.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021062

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Well, yeah okay!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      async: true,
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://san.gotdns.ch:8025/json",
      success: function(result) {
        $("#div1").html(result);
      },
      jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
      failure: function() {},
      complete: function(data) {
          $("#div2").html("Success : ");
          if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {

            //document.write("Success : ");
            //document.write(data);
          } else {
            document.writeln("Failed");
          }
        }
        // -----
    });
  },5000); // delay of 5 seconds
});
```

Comment: @user2181397 what is the name of function `setTimeout(function(){` so I can call it on startup or when I want from anywhere ?